# Directory theme of apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, directory

I have a server with a web site. My document root is `/var/www`.

My configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername www.eeeeeb.fr
        ServerAdmin max@eeeeeb.fr

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None

        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RedirectMatch ^/$ /wiki/
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't understand what the first Directory directive is for.

In the directive, is the "/" for the filesystem `/var/www` or `/`?

If it's for `/var/www` that means the first directory can be replace by the second... Right?

Answer (score 1):

`<Directory>` directives are file system directories. `<Location>` directives are parts of the URL.

I'd assume there's virtual directories that point to outside the `/var/www/` structure (or used to be).

It's normal to have the `/` Directory directive, but it's usually more like:

```
<Directory />
        Deny from All
        Options None
</Directory>
```

Which helps prevent accidentally exposing directories outside the "normal" structure.

<sub>Side note: pointing directly to `/var/www` is a "simplistic" scheme with plenty of drawbacks when you start doing anything mildly complicated. You should be using something like `/var/www/$site_name/data`. If you only have one website, just name the folder "default" or "apache" or something simple.</sub>